# Eclipse JUnit returns ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm using Eclipse IDE, and when I run a JUnit test class, I usually right-click on the test class, then `Run As` then `JUnit Test`.

When I did this, it returned `ClassNotFoundException` on any test class that I tried to run.
I checked the 'Source' tab under project Properties and everything seems fine.

The JUnit test classes ran just fine after I went into the `Run Configurations...`, created a custom configuration under `JUnit Test`, clicked the Classpath' tab, checked the box that says 'Use temporary JAR to specify classpath (to avoid classpath limitations)', then clicked run.

I wonder why this is?
Is there a way to fix it so I can run JUnit after doing the right click then run as `JUnit Test`?
I'm using SpringToolSuite4. I tried `Maven`->`Update Project`, and it didn't work. I also tried `mvn clean test-compile` and `mvn clean install`, it didn't work.
My project is a Maven Project.

Comment: you need maven? then try `mvn clean compile` and then `mvn test` . So test code will compile as well, but then it runs the tests (which may not be immediately desirable if you're trying to run them through Eclipse.)

Comment: Are you using Eclipse 2020-03 or an outdated version? Can you reproduce this issue in Eclipse 2020-03? The temporary JAR file is a trick to work around the maximum command length of the command line (I guess you on Windows with a lot of dependencies).

Comment: We saw the same problem with 2019-12, and it's fixed in 2020-03.

Answer (score 0):

I was using SpringToolSuite 4.5.1 release, I uninstalled that and installed the 4.6.0 release and the problem is now solved. I'm not exactly sure what caused it.